# chart.js ajax pushing another dataset always "undefined"

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

Following is my javascript Code, but the only thing really relevant is the last function. I want to update the Chart to add another dataset, without reloading the Page. But for reason the added dataset is always undefined. The commented-out line, which uses the exact same array of data, on the other hand works. Since I'm new to javascript I'm not sure, if I missed something obvious, or if chart.js just doesn't support this kind of thing at all.

```js
const CHART = document.getElementById("lineChart");

var dts1 = [
 {
  label: "Abfall gesamt",
  data: Abfall_gesamt,
 }
];

var dts2 = [
 {
  label: "Abfall schadstoffhaltiger",
  data: Abfall_schadstoff,
 }
];

var lineChart = new Chart(CHART, {
 type: 'line',
    data: {
     labels: Jahr,
  datasets: dts1
    }
});

function myFunction(){
 //lineChart.data.datasets[0].data = Abfall_schadstoff;
 lineChart.data.datasets.push(dts2);
 lineChart.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, you are defining your datasets (`dts1` and `dts2`) as an *array*. They should be an *object*, like so ...

```
var dts1 = {
    label: "Abfall gesamt",
    data: Abfall_gesamt,
};
var dts2 = {
    label: "Abfall schadstoffhaltiger",
    data: Abfall_schadstoff,
};
```

and then, when generating the chart, set `datasets` value as ...

```
datasets: [dts1]
```

---

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
const CHART = document.getElementById("lineChart");

var Abfall_gesamt = [1, 2, 3];
var Abfall_schadstoff = [4, 5, 6]

var dts1 = {
    label: "Abfall gesamt",
    data: Abfall_gesamt,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)'
};

var dts2 = {
    label: "Abfall schadstoffhaltiger",
    data: Abfall_schadstoff,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)'
};

var lineChart = new Chart(CHART, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Jahr', 'Mahr', 'Kadr'],
        datasets: [dts1]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    stepSize: 1
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

function myFunction() {
    //lineChart.data.datasets[0].data = Abfall_schadstoff;
    lineChart.data.datasets.push(dts2);
    lineChart.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<button id="add" onclick="myFunction()">Add Dataset</button>
<canvas id="lineChart" height="190"></canvas>
```